# more than compilation steps in pom.xml

Tags: maven

I have pom.xml with the structure like:

```xml
<plugins>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
                 ... some directories with .java files to compile.
```

...

```
<plugin>  --- some my plugin that generates one more dir with .java files.
```

At this point I want to compile the newly generated files, so I repeat here step 1 with different content of "includes" element. Second compilation does not happen at all. Please advice.

Comment: In what phase is your generator plugin running? It should run before the `compile` phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plugin should run in `generate-sources` phase. Then you have to make sure that the generated source is available during the normal `compile` phase.

Your plugin should be configured something like this:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>your.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>your-generator-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>your-generator-version</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>your-generator-goal</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Here goes all the plugin configuration -->
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

You can directly from your plugin (mojo) add the compilation source path to use.

Here is an example of what you must add to your mojo:

```java
/**
 * The current project representation.
 * @parameter expression="${project}"
 * @required
 * @readonly
 */
private MavenProject project;

/**
 * Directory wherein generated source will be put; main, test, site, ... will be added implictly.
 * @parameter expression="${outputDir}" default-value="${project.build.directory}/src-generated"
 * @required
 */
private File outputDir;
```

And something like this must be added to your `execute()` method:

```java
if (!settings.isInteractiveMode()) {
    LOG.info("Adding " + outputDir.getAbsolutePath() + " to compile source root");
}
project.addCompileSourceRoot(outputDir.getAbsolutePath());
```

---

This will output the generated java source files into `target/src-generated/` but that can either be changed to some other default value in your mojo **OR** by adding this to the configuration part of the plugin:

```
<outputDir>path/to/my/generated/source/</outputDir>
```

---

The generated java source files will automatically be included in the `compile` phase.

Comment: There is no problem with directories - my mojo reads from and write to known ones. The problem is that the first compilation out of total two is to be run before the <phase>generate-sources</phase> suggested above. Maven does not seem to tolerate "compile" ahead of "generate", at least not so simple.

Comment: Once again - the desired sequence is compile->generate->compile.

Comment: @Dima I understand. That is achievable by using some other phases. I can take a look at it on Monday. Now it's weekend :-)

Comment: I looked into aggregation pom option. It seems to require to change all the current directory structure. It is regrettable because it would impact existing ant files. It seems that one small feature currently absent in maven could help - the pom files would better have been permitted other names than hardcoded pom.xml and accordingly the <module> element would be permitted to contain pom files names besides directories only.